# STM32L0 LoRaWAN Discovery Board: Trigger RTC Alarm Every 250 Milliseconds

Tags: c, stm32, stm32ldiscovery

Ultimately, what I would like to do is to trigger an alarm to wake up the STM32L0 every 250 milliseconds, do some functionality, and then go back into sleep mode. What I am attempting to do now with this code as a proof of concept for the RTC Alarm. It is to trigger the alarm every second. This is confirmed by the `wake_up_flag=1` in the alarm callback. I am using a custom printf function and a function to show RTC time and the value of the wake up flag, which I excluded to focus on the code related to my problem.

The problem is the RTC seems to be working and keeping track of time, but the alarm callback never triggers and I do not have any idea why. I produced most of this code with STM32CubeIDE and to the best of my knowledge, enabled everything I needed to. I am new to STM32CubeIDE and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Main Loop:

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */


  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */

  while (1)
  {
      RTC_TimeShow();
      my_printf("WAKE UP FLAG %d\n" ,wake_up_flag);
      if(wake_up_flag == 1){
          wake_up_flag = 0;
          my_printf("WOKE UP");

      }
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Alarm Callback:

```
void HAL_RTC_AlarmEventCallback(RTC_HandleTypeDef *hrtc){
    wake_up_flag = 1;
}
```

RTC Initialization:

```
static void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{

  /* Enable the RTC Alarm Interrupt */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 0 */

  RTC_TimeTypeDef sTime = {0};
  RTC_DateTypeDef sDate = {0};
  RTC_AlarmTypeDef sAlarm = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 1 */
  /** Initialize RTC Only 
  */
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
  hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Check_RTC_BKUP */

  /* USER CODE END Check_RTC_BKUP */

  /** Initialize RTC and set the Time and Date 
  */
  sTime.Hours = 0x0;
  sTime.Minutes = 0x0;
  sTime.Seconds = 0x0;
  sTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
  sTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sDate.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  sDate.Month = RTC_MONTH_JANUARY;
  sDate.Date = 0x1;
  sDate.Year = 0x0;

  if (HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Enable the Alarm A 
  */
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x0;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x0;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x0;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0x0;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
  sAlarm.AlarmTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
  sAlarm.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_ALL;
  sAlarm.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_NONE;
  sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_DATE;
  sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDay = 0x1;
  sAlarm.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_A;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&hrtc, &sAlarm, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
```

GPIO Configuration:

```
/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, PA15_RESERVED_Pin|PA12_RESERVED_Pin|PA1_RESERVED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, PC1_RESERVED_Pin|PC0_RESERVED_Pin|PC2_RESERVED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA15_RESERVED_Pin PA12_RESERVED_Pin PA1_RESERVED_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = PA15_RESERVED_Pin|PA12_RESERVED_Pin|PA1_RESERVED_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB4_RESERVED_Pin PB1_RESERVED_Pin PB0_RESERVED_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = PB4_RESERVED_Pin|PB1_RESERVED_Pin|PB0_RESERVED_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PC13_RESERVED_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = PC13_RESERVED_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(PC13_RESERVED_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC1_RESERVED_Pin PC0_RESERVED_Pin PC2_RESERVED_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = PC1_RESERVED_Pin|PC0_RESERVED_Pin|PC2_RESERVED_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI4_15_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI4_15_IRQn);

}
```

Comment: Where do you set up the  interrupt controller with the address of the callback?

Comment: I am not sure, it might be the code in the GPIO initialization, which I just added. There are Hall interrupts initialized there. If not how do I accomplish that? This is the code that was created on a New Project for this board.

Comment: Update: Ok, so in my STM32L0XX_it.c file there is a file called RTC_IRQHandler(), which handles the interrupt. If I add my function, HAL_RTC_AlarmEventCallback, then it will actually trigger as I expect. I was watching a tutorial from some other IDE which is where I got the naming mixed up. Now I just need to figure out how to do this once every 250 milliseconds.

Comment: Any updates on how to do? If you found the answer, please update the forum.

Comment: @fatalcoder524. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing to modify the RTC.h and RTC.c file with another RTC type like as follows:

In RTC.h, I modified and added another Alarm match for 250 milliseconds as below.

```
enum AlarmMatch: uint8_t {
    MATCH_250MS        = 7,      //Every 256 milliseconds
    MATCH_ANY          = 0,      // Every Second
    MATCH_SS           = 1,      // Every Minute
    MATCH_MMSS         = 2,      // Every Hour
    MATCH_HHMMSS       = 3,      // Every Day
    MATCH_DHHMMSS      = 4,      // Every Month
    MATCH_MMDDHHMMSS   = 5,      // Every Year
    MATCH_YYMMDDHHMMSS = 6,      // Once, on a specific date and a specific time
};
```

In `RTC.c` , in the void `RTCClass::AdvanceAlarm()` function, I added the following to the alarm switch. The second parameter was based on seconds. The key was that the third parameter is based on the 32.768KHz crystal (32,768 oscillations per second), so if you want 250 ms, that is 1/4 of 32,768 which is 8192.

```
switch (_alarm_match) {
case MATCH_250MS:
_alarm_calendar.year = calendar.year;
_alarm_calendar.month = calendar.month;
_alarm_calendar.day = calendar.day;
_alarm_calendar.hours = calendar.hours;
_alarm_calendar.minutes = calendar.minutes;
_alarm_calendar.seconds = calendar.seconds;
    stm32l0_rtc_calendar_offset(&_alarm_calendar, 0, 8192, &_alarm_calendar);
    break;
```